# Reset to git commit except for my recent commit

Tags: git, github

So here's the problem at the moment.

So I grabbed the upstream branch and made some changes and created a commit.

I have an employer now telling me I need to make a PR to his branch. But his branch isn't updated to the latest commit like how my is.

So when I do make a PR, It's also bringing all of the commits in between his branch and the upstream. I just wanna use my latest commnit.

Assuming that the person is stubborn and doesn't want to update his branch. How would I go about this?

My solution at the moment is to just reset to his current branch and pretty much manually add all of my changes and then create the commit. It would take too long.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your commit (or set of commits) to a new commit (or set of commits) that comes after the latest commit the other person has.

This is a little confusing, so it might help to have three people's names here.  You have your own commit(s), which we might label `V` for Viet.  There are (at least) two other people involved: your employer `E`, and your upstream `U`.

Your upstream *was* the latest:

```
...--E--F--G--H--I   <-- master (in U)
```

You cloned their repository, getting all their commits, then added your own:

```
...--E--F--G--H--I   <-- upstream/master (in V)
                  \
                   J--K--L   <-- master (in V)
```

Meanwhile your employer is behind:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master (in E)
```

If you make a pull request, your request says "take commits through `L`".  For Mr U, that's your three commits, `J--K--L`, because his `master` ends at `I`.  For Mr E, though, that's your three commits plus Mr U's two.

So if you now copy your original commits to new commits that come after `G`:

```
             J'--K'--L'   <-- anotherbranch (in V)
            /
...--E--F--G--H--I   <-- upstream/master (in V)
                  \
                   J--K--L   <-- master (in V)
```

you can now send, to Mr E, a request that he pull commit `L'`.  Since his string of commits ends at commit `G`, that will send him `J'`, `K'`, and `L'`.

Mr E will, eventually, probably have to update to match `U`.  When he does, he must decide what to do with the fact that he ends up with *both* `J'--K'--L'` *and* `J--K--L`.  You, too, must decide whether to keep both copies of your commits.

Note: you can do this commit copying operation using `git cherry-pick` (which is quite straightforward), or using `git rebase` (which is a kind of *automated* cherry-pick with a final `git reset` at the end to move a branch name, so as to "forget" the original commits in favor of the new copies).  The cherry-pick is conceptually simpler, and since this particular operation is "going backwards" (backporting), I would personally stick with it here unless some other (unforeseen / undisclosed) considerations override that.

Comment: Appreciate the explanations :) A lot easier to understand now

Answer (score 1):

You can use cherry picking: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick
Create a new branch by cherry picking the commit you want to include in your PR. 
And create your PR.

Comment: Thank you! Cherry pick was the way to go